# OSX Xcode - Packaging dependencies libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, libmysql

This may well have been asked before I just couldn't figure out the right term to search.

I'm writing a client-server application to run on an OSX desktop which will talk to a MySQL server on the local network.  It seems long-winded to implement a web-services API when basically a bunch of SQL statements will be perfect internally.

I've wrestled with the install procedure for MySQL server on my development machine, ad had to resort to symlinking libmysqlclient.18.dylib into /usr/lib even though i'd put the include path in header search paths.

What I need to know is how do I create a .app file I can send to other machines that will have access to the libmysqlclient.18.dylib file?

I'm used to Windows having installers to do this and a bit new to OSX programming although i've been doing Obj-c for iDevices for 2 years.

Is there a setting which allows the library to be copied into the .app file or do I need to install the mysql connector on each machine - if so, how do I get around the symlink issue, ideally I need it to work from the stock folders.

If this has been answered somewhere else, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At build time the static linker on OS X, ld, writes the shared library identifier of each library that your application links against in to the application binary. At run time the dynamic linker, dyld, attempts to load each shared library from the paths specified in the application binary. You can see this information using `otool -L YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp`.

The fact you needed to symlink libmysqlclient.18.dylib in to /usr/lib suggests that the shared library identifier of libmysqlclient.18.dylib is something like /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib. To include the library in your .app bundle in a way that your application will use it rather than looking in /usr/lib you need to:

1. Change the shared library identifier of libmysqlclient.18.dylib so that dyld will look for the binary relative to your application binary. This is typically done by running `install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libmysqlclient.18.dylib libmysqlclient.18.dylib`.
2. Copy the modified libmysqlclient.18.dylib in to the Frameworks subdirectroy in your application bundle. This is typically done using a Copy Files build phase in your Xcode project.

You should then be able to verify that the install name written in to your application binary is `@executable_path/../Frameworks/libmysqlclient.18.dylib` rather than `/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib` (using `otool -L YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp` again). If the install name isn't correct then you'll need to ensure that your linker search path is set up to find your modified version of libmysqlclient.18.dylib ahead of any other versions you may have.

Comment: This looks more like the proper way to do it to me as i'm a bit new to the toolchain, I found a workaround in the early hours of this morning which was to statically link the library, in other linker flags you put the path to the .a file and omit the -l before it, the app size increases by the size of the .a file and works when I copy the app bundle to another machine that doesn't have mysql installed.  I'd rather do it the proper way though.  Will leave the question open for a day or two in case anyone else comes up with other suggestions, if not, will accept your answer.  Thanks bdash :)

Comment: @bdash I tried as per your suggestion but the install name in the binary has not changed.  How do I set the linker search path to find the modified version of the libmysqlclient.18.dylib ? I copied the file from the installation directory to the application project directory and then ran the install_name_tool as above.  I then dragged the modified library file to Xcode